# NoFieldsClass::operator new(std::size_t): does the standard allow for it to return the same address each time it's invoked?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, new-operator

As part of an optimization strategy, I would like to "pretend" I'm actually allocating an object on the heap, when in fact I would just reuse a pre-existing object, without the rest of the application ever noticing because no check is performed on the returned address and no fields from the objects will ever have to be accessed. Adding to that, the class constructor has no side effects.

I would therefore like to know whether the following program exhibits a behavior which is well defined, implementation-specific, undefined or invalid altogether, by the word of the standard.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;

    static void *operator new(std::size_t s)  {
        static void *mem = ::operator new(s);

        return mem;
    }

    static void operator delete(void *mem) {
        /* no-op */
    }
};

int main() {
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

    Ptr p1 { new Derived };
    Ptr p2 { new Derived };
    Ptr p3 { new Derived };
    Ptr p4 { new Derived };

    // assert just in this test, not in the real program
    assert(p1 == p2 && p2 == p3 && p3 == p4);

    return 0;
}
```

Reading §6.7.2.9 of the current C++ working draft ([N4835](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4835.pdf)) it seems it's invalid:

> Two objects with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if
>   one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a subobject of zero size and they are of different types; **otherwise, they have distinct addresses and occupy disjoint bytes of storage** ²⁹.

However, the note 29 which the above paragraph refers to, states that:

> Under the “as-if” rule **an implementation is allowed to store two objects at the same machine address** or not store an object at all **if the program cannot observe the difference**.

As stated at the beginning, in my case the program couldn't care less about the address at which this object is allocated, all that is required is that it can be allocated with `operator new` and gotten rid of with `operator delete`, so it seems to fit within the requirements made by note 29. Is this correct?

Comment: The `p1 == p2` etc. means your program cares very much about the addresses of the objects. The program indeed observes the difference.

Comment: That's just an assert I used in the example to show what I want the result to be. The real program performs no such check.

Comment: The "as-if" rule gives permission to the "implementation" - the compiler, linker, standard libraries, etc. - not to C++ programs.

Comment: If you breakpoint the constructor, does it get called a 2nd time.  If so I don't think this is going to work.  Feeling very XY-problem(ish).  Why not just use a singleton?

Comment: The constructor gets called, but is a do-nothing constructor. I should perhaps specify this in the question. A singleton is of no use here, because this is just a specific case of other cases that wouldn't use this approach. As the example shows, the `operator new` is overloaded only in one of the possibly infinite amount of derived classes.

Comment: @aschepler, I thought of that, but then again the whole draft applies only to "implementations": [intro.scope] _"This document specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language."_. I would add that the program knows much better what it needs than any generic implementation can know, therefore it can guarantee that the _as-if_ rule applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2** The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage... If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be a
>   non-null pointer value (7.11) `p0` **different from any previously returned value** `p1`, unless that value `p1` was subsequently passed to an `operator delete`.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't spot that myself. However, I wonder two things: 1) How does this fit with the as-if rule cited above? 2) Is there any real possibility that returning the same address can produce an ill-behaving program, within its own specific domain where it's guaranteed that the "as-if" rule above applies?

Comment: 1) I don't see how the as-if rule is relevant. 2) Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Personally, I wouldn't rely on it, but some people like to live dangerously.